# URL building for login 

Tags: html, url, authentication, django-forms, django-templates

I am working on a Django project, in which a template login.html has code like -

```
<form name="input" action="welcome.html" method="get">
--------------SOME FORM ELEMENTS-----------------
<input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

When I click on Login, I want URL to be -

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/welcome.html
```

or

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/welcome.html?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

but url comes out to be

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/login.html/welcome.html?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

(that is, "action" from form gets appended to the URL instead of getting appended to the domain) where "xxxxxxxx" stands for query submitted through form.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<form name="input" action="/welcome.html" method="get">`

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me how to remove the query part from URL, after "?"

Comment: Yes, you should use POST, rather then GET for method.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the action to be "/welcome.html".

Answer (score 0):

thats really wired, try making your `action="/welcome.html"`

Comment: `./welcome.html` is parsed in the same way as `welcome.html`.